# Is it useful to create a collection of generic function types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

This is a question about Haskell style.

As a tutorial example, I created a little program that supports `undo` and `redo` operations. It uses a data structure with two stacks.

```
data History a = History [a] [a]
```

The first stack is a history of, say a game. The second stack stores states that were popped by `undo`. So

```
undo (History (x:xs) redoStack) = History xs (x:redoStack)
undo history = history -- in case there is nothing to undo
```

and

```
redo (History hStack (x:redoStack)) = History (x:hStack) redoStack 
redo history = history -- in case there is nothing to redo
```

There is also a generic operation that applies a change to the current state.

```
applyAChange change (History (x:xs) _) = History ((change x):x:xs) []
```

The type of `applyAChange` is

```
applyAChange :: (a -> a) -> History a -> History a
```

I decided to define a `Change` type:

```
type Change a = a -> a
```

Then the type of `applyAChange` becomes

```
applyAChange :: Change a -> Change (History a)
```

That seemed useful, and I used the `Change` type elsewhere in the code.

---

In defining the `String` **instance** I found myself defining a number of functions with types like:

```
convertASomethingToString :: Something -> String
```

So I defined a `ToString` type

```
type ToString a = a -> String
```

This allowed me to write the preceding functions with types

```
convertASomethingToString :: ToString <Something>
```

All that seems nice and makes the code more informative. My questions are

1. How much of this sort of thing is worth doing?
2. As long as one does it, does it make sense to create a module that consists of these sorts of type definitions and import it? Is that a standard thing to do?
3. Is there already a widely-used module of this sort with useful types?

Thanks.

Comment: In support of this type of refactoring, your `Change` type is a re-invention of the `Endo` type in `Data.Monoid`: `newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }`.

Comment: @RussAbbott I would put the "current state" in a separate slot of the datatype instead of bundling it with one of the lists. It is natural to assume that there will always be a "current state", after all.

Comment: @chepner, but `Endo` is actually useful, because `Endo a` has a `Monoid` instance. Less usefully, perhaps, `Endo` is an exponential functor. The `Change` type synonym, on the other hand, seems to do little more than obfuscate. But that's my opinion of most type synonyms.

Comment: @dfeuer That could be the kernel of an answer. The idea expressed in the question is very good, but a `type` synonym doesn't let you do anything interesting with it.

Comment: @dfeuer I never said it was an *identical* type; my point was that there is already a standard (and as you mentioned, a more useful) wrapper around functions of type `a -> a`.

Answer (score 2):

As it was mentioned earlier, you can use `Endo a` newtype from `Data.Monoid` instead of your `Change` type alias. It may be inconvenient sometimes to deal with wrapping/unwrapping. But you can find something useful in it's `Monoid` instance if you want composable *changes*.

Regarding your `History` data type: it is well-known `ListZipper` in Haskell world. You can read about this concept in different places. But in your code you can already use existing package on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListZipper

It has your functions and some others that you may find helpful.

`ToString` type alias is basically a type of `show` function without `Show` constraint. I don't know how you can convert something generic to `String` without `Show` type bound but I can't say more without looking at your code. So, my point here, is that you basically don't need `ToString` type alias. It is better to use standard functions and type classes.